# Umbraco 7.3.4 - Custom Data Type Value Doesn't Change

Tags: angularjs, content-management-system, umbraco7

I have created a custom data type to deal with character limits on text areas.

I have previously been following a demo where $scope.info = "Hello World" before the user started typing in the text area.

I have since deleted this so it should have removed this text from the umbraco content interface.

But it is still showing the "Hello World" On the right side of the text box.

Customer Editor Angular Controller:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("My.CustomEditorController", function 

    ($scope, notificationsService) {
        $scope.info = "";

        $scope.limitChars = function () {
            var limit = parseInt($scope.model.config.limit);

            if ($scope.model.value.length > limit) {
                $scope.info = "You cannot write more than " + limit + " characters!";
                $scope.model.value = $scope.model.value.substr(0, limit);
                notificationsService.remove(0);
                notificationsService.warning($scope.info);

            }
            else {
                $scope.info = "You have " + (limit - $scope.model.value.length) + " characters left.";
            }
        }

       });
```

Comment: have you tried to increment the version in the config/ClientDependency.config? seems like a caching issue on some level

Comment: @Eyescream Hi, this worked! Thanks and did a bit more reading regarding the use of ClientDependency. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have you tried to increment the version in the
>   config/ClientDependency.config? seems like a caching issue on some
>   level – Eyescream

Did this and it worked.